# Expandable List View setonchildlistener not working

Tags: kotlin

I was working with expandable list view in kotlin. I wanted it to open a new activity when I clicked on a child in the list. But I couldn't do it. If you know of a way to do this, please be helpful.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sESz.png)
this tried method

Answer (score 0):

try with method: setOnItemClickListener  instead of childClickListener.

Comment: thank you for your answer but i don't know how to do it in expandable listview. It would be better if you show a source.

Comment: your screen show this row:
binding.eListView.setOnChildClickLister.

try with:
binding.eListView.setOnItemClickListener.

Answer (score 0):

```
expandableListView.setOnChildClickListener { parent, v, groupPosition, childPosition, id ->
var intent: Intent? = null
when (childPosition) {
    0 -> intent = Intent(this, FirstActivity::class.java)
    1 -> intent = Intent(this, SecondActivity::class.java)
    2 -> intent = Intent(this, ThirdActivity::class.java)
    // diğer öğelerin tıklama işlemleri buraya eklenir
}
intent?.let {
    startActivity(it)
}
true
```

}

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?